# No adapter attached; skipping layout fragment Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, layout, adapter

This is my code and I can't see what is the problem. The error I keep seeing is `No adapter attached; skipping layout`.

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BikesRevisited"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

ADAPTER:

```
package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.R
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models.BikeModel
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models.BikeResult
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.bikes_custom_row.view.*


class Adapter(
    var bikeList: ArrayList<BikeResult>,
    val bikesOnClickEvent:(BikesOnClickEvent)->Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.bikes_custom_row, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var myHolder = holder as MyViewHolder
        myHolder.bindData(bikeList[position], position)


    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bindData(itemModel: BikeResult, position: Int) {
            itemView.city_TV.text = itemModel.city
            itemView.country_TV.text = itemModel.country


        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return bikeList.size
    }
}
```

BIKES ON CLICK EVENT:

```
package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.adapters

import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models.BikeResult

sealed class BikesOnClickEvent {
    data class BikesClicked(val bike:BikeResult):BikesOnClickEvent()

}
```

APISERVICEBUILDER:

```
 package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.api
    
    import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    import retrofit2.Retrofit
    import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
    
    object ApiServiceBuilder {
        val client=OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
        val retrofit= Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.citybik.es/v2/")
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    
    fun <T>buildService(service:Class<T>):T{
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
    
    
    
    }
```

BIKESAPI:

```
package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.api

import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models.BikeModel
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface BikesApi {
    @GET("networks")
    fun getBikes(): Call<BikeModel>
}

BIKE MODEL
package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models

class BikeModel (val networks:ArrayList<BikeResult> )

BIKE RESULT

package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models

class BikeResult (
    val city:String,val country:String


        )

BIKE FRAGMENT

package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recycler_view.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.adapters.Adapter
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.api.ApiServiceBuilder
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.api.BikesApi
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models.BikeModel
import com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.models.BikeResult
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recycler_view.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class BikeFragment:Fragment() {


    var request=ApiServiceBuilder.buildService(BikesApi::class.java)


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view,container,false)
        val call=request.getBikes()
        call.enqueue(object :Callback<BikeModel>{


            override fun onResponse(call: Call<BikeModel>, response: Response<BikeModel>) {
             if (response.isSuccessful){
                 var bikeResponse=response.body()
                 var bikeList=bikeResponse?.networks
                 if (bikeList!=null){
                     var bikelistAdapter=Adapter(bikeList){

                     }
                     recycler_view.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(context)
                     recycler_view.adapter=bikelistAdapter

                 }
             }

else{}


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BikeModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(activity,t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }

        })




            return view

    }



}
```

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

SPLASH FRAGMENT:

```
package com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class SplashFragment:Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash,container,false)

    }




   override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        GlobalScope.launch {
           Thread.sleep(1500)
           findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_bikeFragment)
        }
    }



}

layouts

activity_main

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

bikes_custom_row

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UseCompoindDrawables">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city_TV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="city"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/country_TV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="country"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />






        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>

recycler_view

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

splash

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


navigation_graph

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.SplashFragment"
        android:label="SplashFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_bikeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/bikeFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bikeFragment"
        android:name="com.gsixacademy.android.bikesrevisited.BikeFragment"
        android:label="BikeFragment" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: This is just too much code. Is there anyway you could cut this down to just the relevant bits (as far as you can tell) and leave off anything is likely unrelated? It might be useful to see the exact wording of the error as well?

Comment: Thank you very much for finding the time to review my issue with this simple app....the thing is I don't really know where to find the problem with this code, and that's the reason why I pasted everything. But ,I noticed that this error
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout is appearing on multiple apps I have in my pc...
Again...thank you very much...
Sincerely

Filip